# sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I'm trying to write a request handler to help me send request in async mode. It prompt when I close the python terminal with Ctrl+D or exit()

It shows `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited`

```
import asyncio
import urllib.request
import json 

class RequestHandler:
    def SendPostRequest(method="post",url=None, JsonFormatData={}):
        # Encode JSON
        data =json.dumps(JsonFormatData).encode('utf8')
        # Config Request Header
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')      
        # Send request and wait the response
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data=data)    
        return response 

    async def AsyncSend(method="post",url=None, JsonFormatData=None):
        if method == "post":
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            task = loop.create_task(SendPostRequest(method="post",url=url,JsonFormatData=JsonFormatData))

###################################
# Example
##### In main python terminal, i run like this:
# from RequestHandler import * 
# RequestHandler.AsyncSend(method="post",url="xxxxxx", JsonFormatData={'key':'value'} )
```

When I Click Ctrl+D , it prompted

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'RequestHandler.AsyncSend' was never awaited
```

Is that I shall ignore it? I don't wanna call `await`, as i don't care if the process is success or not.

In this link "https://xinhuang.github.io/posts/2017-07-31-common-mistakes-using-python3-asyncio.html", it said that "To execute an asynchronous task without await, use loop.create_task() with loop.run_until_complete()", is that wrong then?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you're confusing JS async API with Python's. In Python, when you call a coroutine function it returns a coroutine (similar to an armed generator) but doesn't schedule it in the event loop. (i.e. doesn't run/consume it)

You have two options:

1) You can await it via `await` or the older `yield from`.

2) You can `asyncio.create_task(coroutine_function())`. This is the equivalent of calling a promise in JS without giving it a handler or awaiting it.

The warning you're seeing is telling you that the coroutine didn't run. it was only created, but not consumed.

As to your code, there are two errors. First urllib is a blocking library, you can't create a task from it, neither can it be ran asynchronously, take a look at `aiohttp.ClientSession` instead.

Second, the warning you're seeing is probably caused by you calling `AsyncSend` synchronously (without awaiting it). Again, in JS this would probably be fine, as everything in JS is async. In Python, you should use one of the two main methods I mentioned above.

If you insist on using a blocking library, you can run it on a different thread so that you don't block the event loop. As Cloudomation mentioned, to do this. you should use `asyncio.run_in_executor(None, lambda: your_urllib_function())`

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
class RequestHandler:
    def SendPostRequest(self, method="post", url=None, JsonFormatData={}):
        # Encode JSON
        data =json.dumps(JsonFormatData).encode('utf8')
        # Config Request Header
        req = urllib.request.Request(url)
        req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')      
        # Send request and wait the response
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req,data=data)    
        return response 

    async def Send(self, method="post", url=None, JsonFormatData=None):
        if method == "post":
            bound = functools.partial(self.SendPostRequest, method="post", url=url, JsonFormatData=JsonFormatData)
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            await loop.run_in_executor(None, bound)

    def SendAsync(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.Send())
```

Comment: but i need to make it as async function.

Comment: The `SendPostRequest` seems to be an async function which is called in the background using `loop.create_task`. Calling `AsyncSend` synchronously will schedule the task and exit immediately.

Comment: "TypeError: a coroutine was expected, got <http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7f1e4774e4e0>"
<----------  Error like this will be given if i remove async.
|| what if i have several python program to push data to an api, so i need to use AsyncSend right? then i should keep async then?

Comment: @Question-erXDD my previous answer was wrong, please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, i fix the problem with your great help as well, just need to add  "def __init__(self):" if necessary

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error with **`test()`** as shown below:

```py
async def test():
    print("test")

test() # Here
```

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test' was never awaited RuntimeWarning:
> Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

So, I used [**asyncio.run()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) for **`test()`**, then the error above is solved:

```py
import asyncio

async def test():
    print("test")

asyncio.run(test()) # Here
```