# TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py, coroutine

Im trying to get my bot to create a server (guild) and im having the issue of it saying its not awaiting even though i made it await.

ive tried awaiting it

```py
import discord, random, string, asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

def randomString(stringLength=10):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


Token = ""
client = discord.Client()

print("-----------------------------------")
print("|             Choices             |")
print("|       (1) Token Banner          |")
print("-----------------------------------")

Choice = input("Which choice would you like to choose?: ")

if Choice == "1":
    Token = input(str("What token would you like to get banned?: "))

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Logged in as: %s" % Token)

    @client.create_guild
    async def start_creation():
        await client.create_guild(randomString(10), region=None, icon=None)

    asyncio.run(start_creation())


    client.run(Token, bot=False)
```

Expected: Create a server with a random string, no region, no icon
Actual Results: Coroutine Issue
Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 31, in <module>
    asyncio.run(start_creation())
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.create_guild' was never awaited
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756888/sys1-runtimewarning-coroutine-was-never-awaited)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use [`Client.create_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_guild) as a decorator, which it is not.

Your code is equivalent to

```
async def temp():
    await client.create_guild(randomString(10), region=None, icon=None)

start_creation = client.create_guild(temp)
```

So `start_creation` is a coroutine object, which is awaitable but not callable.

Comment: So it can't be called from outside an async function?