# Can't make a discord bot send a message inside a python function

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I would like to create a discord bot that sends a message in a specific channel, when a twitter account follows a new account.

I managed to work with the twitter API, but i cant make the part where it sends the message on discord, it's just a string to send in a function

I keep seeing discord bots that reacts to commands typed in a channel, but i want to have a bot that sends message by himself and not wait for a command.

i don't really understand the async things (https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task.py) i couldnt figure it out by myself can someone try to help me please

```
def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape):

friendUserScreenName = friendUser.screen_name
friendUserDescription = friendUser.description
friendUserFollowersCount = str(friendUser.followers_count)
client = discord.Client() 

discordMessage = "\n\n=======================================================\n\n" + "** User @" + eachUserToScrape + " started following : @" + friendUserScreenName + " **\n\nLink profile : https://twitter.com/" + friendUserScreenName + "\n\nSubscribers count : "+ friendUserFollowersCount + "\n\nDescription : " + friendUserDescription

channel = client.get_channel(...)
print(discordMessage + type(discordMessage))
await channel.send(discordMessage)
```

Comment: If you don't understand async you should really consider learning it before diving any deeper into `discord.py`, otherwise it can get really messy and really difficult. Also I'm sure you're getting an error like: `'await' outside async function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Łukasz Kwieciński said, you'll be getting an `'await' outside async function` error. To check if the code works and let be the `screen_name` and `description` attributes, I made a class, assuming your `whostartedfollowing` and `whoisbeingfollowed` are of a class that resembles `user`:

```py
class user:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_name = "screen name"
        self.description = "description"
        self.followers_count = 3
```

Coming to the actual part of the question: sending a message without `await`ing for a command, you can send the message anytime you want. For example, you can send the message when the bot starts using its `on_ready()` method, something like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready(): #When the bot starts
    print(f"The bot is online and is logged in as {client.user}")
    #Do some scraping here and get the actual whostartedfollowing and whoisbeingfollowed (from Twitter).
    whostartedfollowing:user = user()
    whoisbeingfollowed:user = user()
    await sendDiscordMessage(whoisbeingfollowed, whostartedfollowing)
    print("sent the message")
```

in which `sendDiscordMessage()` is the function in your code, but a bit modified to reduce errors:

```py
async def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape):

    friendUserScreenName = friendUser.screen_name
    friendUserDescription = friendUser.description
    friendUserFollowersCount = str(friendUser.followers_count)
    
    discordMessage = "\n\n=======================================================\n\n" + "** User @" + eachUserToScrape.screen_name + " started following : @" + friendUserScreenName + " **\n\nLink profile : https://twitter.com/" + friendUserScreenName + "\n\nSubscribers count : "+ friendUserFollowersCount + "\n\nDescription : " + friendUserDescription
                                                                                                        #Since screen_name is a string, I just used it instead of the object, so it can be joined with the rest as a string.
    channel = client.get_channel(...) #Get the channel with its ID (an `int`), for example a channel with 
    print(channel) #To check if the channel is None or not.
    print(discordMessage) #and not "print(discordMessage + type(discordMessage))", or you can use "print(discordMessage + str(type(discordMessage)))"
    await channel.send(discordMessage)
```

You can do the same thing without `await`ing, by not making your `sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape)` function `async` (letting it be `sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape)` and not adding `async` to make it `async def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape)`), if you don't want to depend on the result of the `await`ed coroutine. But, you'll get a [`RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756888/sys1-runtimewarning-coroutine-was-never-awaited).

If you have to wait for the result of the awaited coroutine, where if the awaited coroutine crashes, then the rest of the code won't work either, or where the order of execution is important, then use `await` and change `def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape)` to:

```py
async def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape):
```

Also, you're [using `discord.Client` and not `discord.ext.commands.Bot`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51235308/16136190). The latter is just an extension of the former, with more features. You may want to switch to `commands.Bot`.

Here's the full code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="")

class user:
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_name = "screen name"
        self.description = "description"
        self.followers_count = 3

@client.event
async def on_ready(): #When the bot starts
    print(f"Bot online and logged in as {client.user}")
    #Do some scraping here and get the actual whostartedfollowing and whoisbeingfollowed (from Twitter).
    whostartedfollowing:user = user()
    whoisbeingfollowed:user = user()
    await sendDiscordMessage(whoisbeingfollowed, whostartedfollowing)
    print("sent the message")

async def sendDiscordMessage(friendUser, eachUserToScrape):

    friendUserScreenName = friendUser.screen_name
    friendUserDescription = friendUser.description
    friendUserFollowersCount = str(friendUser.followers_count)
    
    discordMessage = "\n\n=======================================================\n\n" + "** User @" + eachUserToScrape.screen_name + " started following : @" + friendUserScreenName + " **\n\nLink profile : https://twitter.com/" + friendUserScreenName + "\n\nSubscribers count : "+ friendUserFollowersCount + "\n\nDescription : " + friendUserDescription
                                                                                                        #Since screen_name is a string, I just used it instead of the object, so it can be joined with the rest as a string.
    channel = client.get_channel(...)
    print(channel)
    print(discordMessage) #and not "print(discordMessage + type(discordMessage))", or you can use "print(discordMessage + str(type(discordMessage)))"
    await channel.send(discordMessage)

client.run("token")
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50757497/simplest-async-await-example-possible-in-python) are some uses of `async`-`await`.

Comment: I mean, thank you for your time, I was maybe to fast on the learning part and started working on it without that much knowledge..

Comment: Your explanations are perfect, thank you for everything !