# aiortc - how to just send a message over a data channel?

Tags: python, webrtc, python-asyncio, aiortc

*I just want to send a message...* browser to server - button presses/whatever.    server to browser - ROS information (other than video, e.g., battery level.)

The examples clearly show how to receive and send a message.    In the examples/server.py code:

```
    # pc is an RTCPeerConnection
    @pc.on("datachannel")
    def on_datachannel(channel):
        @channel.on("message")
        def on_message(message):
            if isinstance(message, str) and message.startswith("ping"):
                channel.send("pong" + message[4:])
```

I've searched and haven't found any 'send' examples that aren't essentially responding to a received "message" (python side) or "onopen" (js).   This of course gives full context and resides inside an async function (python side.)

What I'd like to do is just have a simple, global function akin to this:

```
var dc = None    # global, set in event "datachannel"
def sendMessage(msg)     # This is what I want!   Both python and JS side
    if (dc != None):
        dc.send(msg)

async def offer(request):
    global dc
    ...
   @pc.on("datachannel")
    def on_datachannel(channel):
        global dc
        dc = channel

# and set dc to None if connection fails or ended
```

This fails -

```
Exception in thread Thread-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1378, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/pg/workspaces/isaac_ros-dev/src/pywebrtc/pywebrtc/server.py", line 112, in betterPong
    sendMessage("betterPong")
  File "/home/pg/workspaces/isaac_ros-dev/src/pywebrtc/pywebrtc/server.py", line 107, in sendMessage
    dc.send(msg)
  File "/home/pg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcdatachannel.py", line 187, in send
    self.transport._data_channel_send(self, data)
  File "/home/pg/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiortc/rtcsctptransport.py", line 1808, in _data_channel_send
    asyncio.ensure_future(self._data_channel_flush())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 615, in ensure_future
    return _ensure_future(coro_or_future, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/tasks.py", line 634, in _ensure_future
    loop = events._get_event_loop(stacklevel=4)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-4'.
/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py:1018: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'RTCSctpTransport._data_channel_flush' was never awaited
```

I'm a newb on asyncio in Python.   If I put async in front of the function and await on the send, I get

```
server.py:112: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sendMessage' was never awaited
```

Hopefully, this is simple!   :)    Best!

Comment: You might get help if you posted some real code.  I mean, this is not valid Python at all (`var` is not a Python keyword), plus there is no actual call to the function `send_message`.  The error messages indicate that you are not starting the asyncio event loop, which you must do to execute an async def function.  But you haven't shown enough code to allow anyone to point out where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution for the Python side...    Diving down into asyncio and a [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756888/sys1-runtimewarning-coroutine-was-never-awaited):

```
dc = None
async def sendMessage(msg):
    if (dc != None):      # dc set to channel in 'on_datachannel'
        dc.send(msg)

# to call, for now a simple timing loop at the outer level
def betterPong():
    asyncio.run( sendMessage("foo foo") )
    threading.Timer(3, betterPong).start()

betterPong()
```

Works.   Is it efficient to create a new coroutine for each send?   to be determined...